# Will cpf be triggered when a document gets added to a collection

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a CPF for a given collection say "collection1" on update and add. now if a document belonging to "collection1" now gets added to another collection "collection2". will the cpf gets triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is still in collection1 (that is, you didn't remove it from collection1, just added collection2), then yes, whatever actions your CPF pipeline have for an update will see this as an update.